# Laravel validation for field if "image/file" is selected?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a field "image", type is **file** and need only to validate if image is selected, means it can be also empty.

I tried it so: `'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:100000',` but so it is also required.

I tried still with parameters `present` and `sometimes` but the field is still required.

How can I validate it only if image is selected?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- If the **"avatar"** field *may not be present* in the **input** array you want to use:

`'avatar' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:100000'`

> In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly accomplish this, add the **sometimes** rule.

---

- If the **"avatar"** field will *absolutely* be in the **input** array and it's value will be then `null` you want to use:

`'avatar' => 'nullable|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:100000'`

> The field under validation may be **null**. This is particularly useful when validating primitive such as strings and integers that can contain null values. To quickly accomplish this, add the **nullable** rule.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, You have to check only if it is present or not null - **Validating When there is value**. So use `sometimes`

> "In some situations, you may wish to run validation checks against a
>   field only if that field is present in the input array. To quickly
>   accomplish this, add the sometimes rule to your rule list"

```
 $v = Validator::make($data, array(
        'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
    ));
```

In your case,

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
        'avatar' => 'sometimes|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:100000',
    ));
```

**Note:**

The following code will do nothing because there are no rules to validate against, done because even if it's present in the POST array, you should specify rules. and the doesn't make any difference.

```
$v = Validator::make($data, array(
    'avatar' => 'sometimes',
));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `'nullable'` in your rules.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-nullable

Answer (score 0):

First check the `$request` object. Check `avatar` is available or not in your request. Then try this:

```
'avatar' => 'sometimes|image|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,gif|max:2048'
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution i found that works best is using `Rule::requiredIf`

```
'cover' => [
    'image',
    Rule::requiredIf(function () {
        if (some_condition) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    })
]
```