# Laravel 9 the field must be a file even though I said it can be nullable (validation)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I have this function in a validation class:

```
public function rules(): array {
    return [
        // ...
        'content_image'       => 'nullable|file|mimetypes:png|max:2000',
        // ...

    ];
}
```

I state, that this can be null, but if it is not, it must be a file that is PNG and a max size of 2mb's

Seems straight forward enough:

The request coming in a FormData from an Api call:

```
content: <p>1</p>
content_image: null // => Should be allowed
live_wire_component: null
page_name: test-page
page_id: 27
order: 1
```

The validation sais no:

```
{
  "content_image": [
    "The content image must be a file.",
    "Images can only be PNG"
  ]
}
```

I am 900% sure this is how you allow a field to be null through validation:

[From the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-nullable)

> nullable
>
> The field under validation may be null.

So why does this want an image even though I said it can be null?

Comment: Try using `sometimes`

Comment: instead of 'content_image' => 'nullable|file|mimetypes:png|max:2000', use 'content_image' => [ 'nullable', 'mimes:png', 'max:2048', ],

Comment: I know it might be not apply to version 9 but just ccheck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53179046/laravel-request-validation-nullable-image

Comment: @TimLewis know that.. but you might didn't experienced that there's a difference when for example you're using that for regex.. the first one will fail.. so.. there's also another difference.. just no need to use 'file' as a rule

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel validation for field if "image/file" is selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588700/laravel-validation-for-field-if-image-file-is-selected)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the sometimes rule as @SergheiLeonenco stated in comment above https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#validating-when-present
also note I modified the 'mimes'

```
public function rules(): array {
    return [
        // ...
        'content_image'       => 'sometimes|file|mimes:png|max:2000',
        // ...

    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your request validation change content_image attribute to this.

```
'content_image'       => 'nullable|file|mime:png|max:2000',
```

i hope it was useful